# Replacing only the matched group in a file with multiple occurences

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

**Input:**  `/* ABCD X 1111 */ /* Comment 1111: [[reason for comment]] */`

**Output:**  `/* ABCD X 1111 # [[reason for comment]] */`

**Regex used**: `regex = (?:[\/*]+\sPRQA[\s\w\,]*)(\*\/\s*\/\*\Comment[\w\,]+:)+(?:\s\[\[.*\/$)`

How to use the above regex to replace the matched group with '#' in a file with multiple occurrences?

I tried with `re.sub(regex, '#\1', file.read(), re.MULTILINE)`, but this will append # to the matched group.

Is there a direct way to do this instead of iterating line by line and then replacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
re.sub(r'(/\*\s*ABCD[^*/]*)\*/\s*/\*\s*Comment[^*:]+:(\s*\[\[[^][]*]]\s*\*/)', r'\1#\2', file.read())
```

If you are sure these substrings only appear at the end of lines, add your `$` anchor back and use `flags=re.M`:

```
re.sub(r'(/\*\s*ABCD[^*/]*)\*/\s*/\*\s*Comment[^*:]+:(\s*\[\[[^][]*]]\s*\*/)$', r'\1#\2', file.read(), flags=re.M)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HzK6QR/1). *Details*:

- `(/\*\s*ABCD[^*/]*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): `/*`, zero or more whitespaces, `ABCD`, and then any zero or more chars other than `*` and `/`
- `\*/\s*/\*\s*Comment[^*:]+:` - `*/`,  zero or more whitespaces, `/`, zero or more whitespaces, `Comment`, one or more chars other than `*` and `:` and then `:`
- `(\s*\[\[[^][]*]]\s*\*/)` - Group 2 (`\2`):  zero or more whitespaces, `[[`, zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, `]]`, zero or more whitespaces, `*/`.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PoqEsc):

```
import re
rx = r'(/\*\s*ABCD[^*/]*)\*/\s*/\*\s*Comment[^*:]+:(\s*\[\[[^][]*]]\s*\*/)$'
text = "Some text ... /* ABCD X 1111 */ /* Comment 1111: [[reason for comment]] */\nMore text here... Some text ... /* ABCD XD 1222 */ /* Comment 1112: [[reason for comment 2]] */"
print( re.sub(rx, r'\1#\2', text, flags=re.M) )
```

Output:

```
Some text ... /* ABCD X 1111 # [[reason for comment]] */
More text here... Some text ... /* ABCD XD 1222 # [[reason for comment 2]] */
```